# bash + run script in the loop cycle

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

we need to run the run.sh on each 10 steps

```
for x in {1..100} ; do
  sleep 1
  /tmp/run.sh
done
```

so finally run.sh will run 10 times

how we can do that?

other example ( in this case run.sh will run 20 times )

```
for x in {1..200} ; do
  sleep 1
  /tmp/run.sh
done
```

Comment: I supposed there are other stuff like `sleep 1` that need to be run on all iterations ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to test if the value of `x` can be divided by 10 :

```
for x in {0..100} ; do
    if (( x % 10 == 0 ))
    then
        /tmp/run.sh
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: +1 for better bash. Using `[` tests and `(( ))` at the same time looks weird

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for the [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)
(`%`) operator.  For example:

```
for x in {1..100} ; do
  sleep 1
  [ $((x % 10)) -eq 0 ] && /tmp/run.sh
done
```

Another example:

```
$ for i in {1..100} ; do  [ $((i % 10)) -eq 0 ] && echo $i  ; done
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
```

Comment: why i ?  should be x

Comment: because i tested it with `$i` in my shell and forgot to change it to $x here.  fixed.

Comment: Why using `[` and `(( ))` at the same time ? Check @Félicien answer

Comment: Personal style choice - i.e. because I wrote it and not someone else.  It's syntactically valid and shorter.  And, IMO, more readable.  One may equally ask "why use `if/then/else` when `[ ... ] && ` will do"?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (( i = 0; i < 10; ++i )); do
    /tmp/run.sh
    sleep 10
done
```

If you want to run the script ten times, then do the loop ten times and sleep the appropriate amount of time in-between.

Or, with a parameter determining how many times to run the script:

```
n=20
for (( i = 0; i < n; ++i )); do
    /tmp/run.sh
    sleep 10
done
```